# Help me identify file type?

Tags: audio, music, mp3

```
$ Scribbling % file 08\ Why.mp3 
08 Why.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0
```

In spite of the name, it is not an MP3 file, which would have identified as

```
$ Scribbling % file /Users/Shared/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/zh-say-140.mp3 
/Users/Shared/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/zh-say-140.mp3: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v2,  64 kbps, 22.05 kHz, Monaural
```

All the programs, including those from Apple, that expect it to be what its extension claims produce no sound.  `play` on command line says "play FAIL formats: can't open input file `08 Why.mp3'"  Others issue no diagnostic at all.

ffmpeg didn't help:

```
WGroleau@MBP Scribbling in the Sand % ffmpeg -i 08\ Why.mp3
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[mp3 @ 0x7faf5f014000] Failed to read frame size: Could not seek to 1026.
08 Why.mp3: Invalid argument
```

Comment: I think the file is corrupted.  Found an MP3 fie that does play where file also omits the "contains" (yet which DOES have ID3 tags in it).

Comment: Have you tried [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/)? It supports a lot of different audio and video file formats. If the file plays, then you can look at the **Media Information** to see what exactly the file is.

Comment: I'll remember that if it happens again.  Already replaced the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the `file` output can be seen on proper MP3 files, and ffmpeg gave error, I compared it to another file with `od -xc` and concluded it is actually an MP3 file but damaged.  How it got damaged within the Music (iTunes) library is unknown.